# How was BOS on the Apple III different from SOS?

Tags: operating-system, apple-iii

The original operating system for the Apple III was [SOS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apple_SOS), a.k.a. "Sophisticated Operating System". Though the Apple III and SOS didn't last very long as the platform was [considered a failure](https://retrocomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/24197/why-was-the-apple-iii-considered-a-failure-if-indeed-it-was), it did have support from a community for several years after that.

In 1993, Bob Consorti produced a "replacement" for SOS called [BOS](https://archive.org/details/Bobs_Operating_System_for_the_Apple_III_1993_On_Three/page/n17/mode/2up) or "Bob's Operating System" if you will. While it appears to be the same thing as SOS, the manual claims that BOS is over 60k lines of code which suggests it might be a re-write or something more extensive.

What exactly is BOS in this regard, and how was it different from SOS? To that extent, is there any reason to still use SOS on an Apple III?